# If fails or copy function fails?

Tags: bash, if-statement, cp

I have a little bash script where I compare two files. If one doesn't exist and second one exists, then I will copy/replace backup to main folder.

Somehow this doesn't seem to work. Hope someone can give a hand on this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "/Folder1/$1.jpg" ] && [ -f "/BU_Folder2/$1_BU.jpg" ]; then
     cp -fp /BU_Folder2/$1_BU.jpg /Folder1/$1.jpg
     cp -fp /BU_Folder2/$1_BU.mp4 /Folder1/$1.mp4
fi
```

Comment: Can you clarify "Some how this doens't seem to work" ?

Comment: did you try `-a` instead of `&&` and using a single `[....]`, i.e. `[ ... -a ... ]`?

Comment: Even there is a backup file, somehow this doesn't copy to main folder. Is there a way to debug this or write a log, when comparison is done and what is the result ?

Comment: And yes, tried also                                                   " if [ ! -f "/Folder1/$1.jpg" -a -f "/BU_Folder2/$1_BU.jpg" ] "          ---- with no help for this one.

Comment: If you want to debug this, split the if into nested if, and run with bash -vx

Answer (score 0):

At the prompt, run the following commands:

```
$ set -- FILENAME # FILENAME is the value you think $1 is supposed to have
$ [ ! -f "/Folder1/$1.jpg" ] && [ -f "/BU_Folder2/$1_BU.jpg" ] && echo success
```

If the last command does not print "success", then your script probably does not have the value for `$1` that you think it does. Add `echo $1` to the top of your script to confirm.

If it does print "success", and your script has no error output from `cp`, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: Hi 
I'm sure that $1 is OK, because this is only one part of the script automaticly started by reboot and there is some other tasks where $1 is used.
If I make own script with excactly the same lines and run it from command promt, it works just fine.

As mentioned, the script is started when booted (/etc/init.d/S99CheckFiles) and can there be some kind user rights issue?

BR,
jii

Comment: Ah, yes. If the current user doesn't have read permissions for /Folder or /BU_Folder2, the test will return false even if the file really does exist.